# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter' in Python 3.11.4

Tags: python, tkinter, ttkthemes

Im getting this error when i try to install ttkthemes on python3.11.4. I updated python from 3.6.9 nad now i cant download ttkthemes. I get the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter'`

I tried `sudo apt-get install python3-tk` but it didnt worked for me

Im using an RPI4 on Ubuntu

Comment: What  is ur OS system?

Comment: Im using Ubuntu on an Raspberry pi 4

Comment: U have Thonny on RPi 4 on it.

Comment: No im using VScode

Comment: U installed VScode on RPI 4?

Comment: Yes im using VScode on my raspberry pi 4

Comment: Okay but that dosent have to do anything with this topic?

Comment: Here is link  https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/raspberry-pi

Comment: For linux only  https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux

Comment: How do you update Python to 3.11.4?